# referencing dynamically loaded things from a previously loaded jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say that i have something like this:

```
<head><script src="script1.js" ...></script></head>
<body><div id="div1"></div></body>
```

which i call index.html, and div1's content is loaded dynamically, like

```
$("#div1").html ("div1.html");
```

where div1.html is something like

```
<div id="div2"><canvas id="canv1" ... /></div>
```

and i want to reference canv1 somehow in script1.js; by just operating on $("#canv1") nothing happens because script1.js is loaded **before** div1.html; is there a way (e.g. $(document).on(...)) to "do something as soon as [..] is loaded"? i tried

```
$(document).on ("load", "#canv1", ...);
```

but it doesn't work. it's worth noticing that $(document).on ("click", "#canv1", ...) works, but it's not what i want (as in, i want to draw something in the canvas before caring of what happens on click...); any ideas?

Comment: `append` should have some `oncomplete` callback, if it loads html file asynchronously

Comment: i don't think that's the issue, although that might solve other minor problems that i have. the way i did it before was to have each dynamically loaded html page to load a script, but then i had scripts within scripts and it was a nightmare like the film inception.

Comment: You really think it is loaded synchronously?

Comment: what would the `oncomplete` callback countain then? e.g. how can i tell it "ok yeah canv1 should show up now, do something with it"?

Comment: How are you actually loading div1.html? Calling `.html("div1.html")` won't do it, but `.load()` would work.

Comment: precisely: `$.ajax ({url: "div1.html", cache: false}).done (function (html) { $("#div1").append (html); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're loading your content with a AJAX call, then doing your append in the callback. If you put the $('#canv1')... after the append, within the callback, it should work.

Edit based on the OP's comment below:

```
$.ajax (
    {url: "div1.html",
     cache: false}).
done (function (html){
    $("#div1").append (html);
    $("#canv1").click(...);
 });
```

Comment: cheers! my mistake was not putting the $("#canv1")-related business IN the callback, but after it.